# Problem with f.write it only write last row in file (Python)?

Tags: python

So I must create a file with  4-1 and 9-3 in each row. After that, I need to do subtraction for each number. I've done something but there is only a result for row 2. So in izrazi.txt is my input 4-1 and 9-3 so my output in izlaz.txt must be 4-1 = 3 and in new row 9-3 = 6

```
with open('izrazi.txt','w') as f: 
    f.write("4-1\n9-3") 
    
with open('izrazi.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        if l[1] == "-":
            rezultat = (l + "=" + str(int(l[0]) - int(l[2])))
        
with open("izlaz.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.write(rezultat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable 'rezultat' outside the for loop and inside the loop use '+=' operator instead of '='.

Change your code like below:

```
rezultat = ''
for l in lines:
    if l[1] == "-":
        rezultat += (l.replace('\n','') + "=" + str(int(l[0]) - int(l[2])) + '\n')
```

Comment: @HamzaBejtić  Always Welcome, please give UpVote to my Answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are overwriting the results variable after each loop.

Due to this, only the value of the result variable *after* the final loop is saved to the file.

You can fix this by making `rezultat` a `list`.

```
with open('izrazi.txt','w') as f: 
    f.write("4-1\n9-3") 
    
with open('izrazi.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    rezultat = []
    for l in lines:
        if l[1] == "-":
            rezultat.append(f"{l}={int(l[0]) - int(l[2])}")
        
with open("izlaz.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.write('\n'.join(rezultat))
```

Comment: This is output from your code(in izlaz.txt): {l}={int(l[0]) - int(l[2])}
{l}={int(l[0]) - int(l[2])}

Comment: My bad, I forgot to make it an f-string. Answer should be updated now.